# WildFly 8.1 domain mode with shared properties

Tags: cluster, share, system-properties, wildfly8

I'm trying to configure a WildFly 8.1 cluster and I have not found any satisfying answer for sharing common property files.
In standalone mode I've added some property files to the configuration folder which can be fetched via the jboss.server.config.dir and the configuration file name. 
Is there a possibility to propagate property files in domain mode? I don't want to add the property content to each server.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

In Domain cluster, your properties really should be maintained in domain.xml

To have the properties NOT on the JVM command-line, and updated immediately, you need to make sure that you are using boot-time=false on each system-property.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is create a jar file with the properties file, you can deploy this jar in the servers groups that you want and in the application add the dependency to this jar.

For example create a jar called `config.jar` put the properties files (eg `settings.properties`) then add the dependency in `MANIFEST.MF` of your application like:

```
Dependencies: deployment.config.jar
```

Now you can access to the properties file as if were included in your deployment.